# Criar mascara personalizada Cartão de Crédito

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde a todos.

Preciso criar uma mascara para um campo texto para mascarar cartão de crédito no seguinte formato:

Sem máscara: 4854 5654 2245 5654 
**Com máscara**: 4854 xxxx xxxx 5654

Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer isso no campo texto?

Comment: Não sei se é uma boa idéia fazer isso no lado do cliente (javascript). Seria melhor já levar para o lado do cliente a string formatada sem o número completo (com máscara) por questões de segurança.

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni, o problema é que é um formulário de login. O cartão de crédito é o login do usuário, ou seja, ele que digita o cartão. Preciso mascarar em quanto ele digita.

Comment: Sempre uso esse plugin http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ me atende bem.

Comment: esse plugin não consegue fazer o que eu preciso, infelizmente. ele até cria a mascara, mas nao esconde os números do meio...